# Consider the polynomial $f_{k}\left ( x \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{k}x ^{i}$. Find ${f_{k}}'\left ( 1 \right )$ in terms of $k$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Consider the polynomial  $f_{k}\left ( x \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{k}x ^{i}$. Find ${f_{k}}'\left ( 1 \right )$ in terms of $k$.

If I think of $f_{k}\left ( x \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{k}x ^{i}$  as $x^{0}+x^{1}+x^{3}+... +x^{k}$, it's derivative would be $1+3x^2+4x^3+ ... +kx^{k-1}$ and ${f_{k}}'\left ( 1 \right )$ would equal $\frac{k^{2}+k}{2}$. 
However, if I think of $f_{k}\left ( x \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{k}x ^{i}$ as $\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$, it's derivative would be $\frac{(x-1)(k+1)x^{k}+(1-x^{k+1})}{(1-x)^{2}}$ (quotient rule) and ${f_{k}}'\left ( 1 \right )$ would be ... $\frac{0}{0}$?

Comment: You dropped $x^2$ in your first version. In the other version one would have to take the limit as $x \to 1$ and doing that would likely get rid of the zero divide.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

$$f_{k}\left ( x \right )=\sum_{i=0}^{k}x ^{i}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^k$$

$$ f'_{k}\left ( x \right )=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...+kx^{k-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k} ix ^{i-1} $$

$$f'_{k}\left ( 1 \right )=1+2+3+4+...+k= \frac {k(k+1)}{2}$$

You can not write your function as $$\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$$ around $x=1$ because it is not defined at $x=1$

Same with your derivative,which is not defined as $x=1.$

Have you tried to simplify your derivative and see what is the result after removing the $(1-x)^2 $ from the top and bottom?

Comment: please read the whole question

Comment: @JenniferLin       Check my edited solution please.